# Extreme points of the unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I want to show that for $X$ compact and Hausdorff, any $f\in C(X)$ satisfying $|f(x)|=1$ for all $x\in X$ is an extreme point of the unit ball of $C(X)$. Here, $C(X)$ is the space of continuous complex-valued functions on $X$.

I tried to prove it by contradiction, writing $f = \frac12(f_1+f_2)$ for distinct $f_1,f_2$ in the unit ball of $C(X)$. Then by the triangle inequality, $|f_1(x)|=|f_2(x)|=1$ for all $x\in X$. But I cannot see how this leads anywhere. Am I missing something obvious?

Anyway, I am quite stuck on this and would appreciate a hint.

Comment: Try it first in the case where $X$ is just a single point.

Comment: @EricWofsey Even in this case I am not sure what goes wrong. Writing $z=(z_1+z_2)/2$ for distinct $z,z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$ of unit magnitude does not seem to yield any contradiction. It feels like I am missing something really basic...

Comment: Well, it's not true of an arbitrary norm.  You have to use something specific about the usual absolute value of complex numbers and how it is defined.

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm not sure if it's what you were thinking, but I figured out how to make an argument exploiting the geometry of the complex plane. My original post shows that $f_1,f_2$ have unit magnitude everywhere. But then the midpoint of the line between $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ lies strictly inside the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Yeah, that's one way to think about it (though that geometric fact about the unit circle requires proof).

Comment: Naively (and writing everything in $\mathbb{R}^2$), the circle is given by $x^2+y^2=1$ and the line between the two points on the boundary is of the form $ax+by=c$. There can be at most two solutions to this system of equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$1).\ $ This seems to be more or less your idea: first prove the more general fact that a point $x$ is an extreme point of the unit ball in a Banach space if and only if for all $t\in X$ we have $\|x\pm t\|\le 1\Rightarrow t=0.$ For one direction, set $y=x+t$ and $z=x-t$ and apply the definition. For the other, write $x=\alpha z+(1-\alpha)w$ and suppose $\alpha\neq 0,1.$

$2).\ $ Suppose $|f(x)|=1.$ Take a $g\neq 0$ so there is an $x_0$ such that $g(x_0)\neq 0$. Now consider what happens if $\|f\pm g\|\le 1.$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the second direction in (1)? I do not see an obvious choice of $t$. Everything else makes sense to me.

Comment: You are not looking for a $t.$ You are assuming that $\|f\pm g\|\le 1$ and want to get a contradiction if $|f(x)|=1.$

Comment: I understood the second part of your answer. I am asking about proving the if and only if statement in the first part.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I figured it out: if $x=\frac12(z+w)$ for distinct $z,w$ in the unit ball, then $t=\frac12(z-w)$ works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes! You are welcome. Glad to help.